# Secure client not using highest TLS version

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssl

I'm updating an old .Net project, it targets .Net Framework 4.8.
The problem is that I'm using HttpClient to POST some data to an endpoint, using code similar to that below (editted for readability)

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData, jsonSettings);
var _client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
var response = _client.PostAsync(endpoint, content).Result;
```

The problem is that it throws a "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." exception. Using Wireshark I can see the connection reaches the correct endpoint, and the remote endpoint returns a Fatal response to the client handshake, but my client is trying to use TLS1.0. I'm using System.Net.Http v4.3.4, and setting SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 seems to make no difference if added or removed (as .Net 4.8 probably doesnt need it).

How do I make my project use Tls1.3 ?

I have another project that calls the same endpoint, and that works OK, but I cant see a difference between them.

Comment: Anything in your app.config (of either project)? IIRC there are some switches there which affect TLS version

Comment: @canton7 - nothing obvious. I've looked at the assemblyBinding entries, and they reference the same versions as my other working project.

Answer (score 1):

OK, totally my fault. My customers endpoint isnt using Tls1.3 !!

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
```

This fixed it. Sorry, thanks for looking.